# pgfplots + ybar interval: Last x tick label not appearing / missing

Tags: pgfplots

I've been trying to make the last x tick label appear to no avail.

[image]

As you can see , everything looks neat on this graph except that tiny little detail. My OCD won't let it sit like that which is why I've come to ask for help. How do I make the "1600" appear?

This is the code I've used to generate this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{width=7.5cm,compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Score Distribution of the 1984 SAT},
    ybar interval,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    xlabel={SAT Scores},
    ylabel={Frequency},
    xmin=200, xmax=1600,
    ymin=0, ymax=18000,
    xtick={200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600},
    ytick={0,3000,6000,9000,12000,15000,18000},
    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=left},
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xmajorgrids=false,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    enlarge x limits=0.03,
]

\addplot coordinates {(1600,5) (1580,27) (1570,19) (1560,39) (1550,75) (1540,96) (1530,108) (1520,188) (1510,217) (1500,278) (1490,316) (1480,404) (1470,473) (1460,617) (1450,601) (1440,795) (1430,874) (1420,1071) (1410,1196) (1400,1323) (1390,1439) (1380,1621) (1370,1871) (1360,2028) (1350,2267) (1340,2495) (1330,2698) (1320,3155) (1310,3334) (1300,3661) (1290,3730) (1280,4099) (1270,4393) (1260,4762) (1250,4923) (1240,5623) (1230,5701) (1220,6143) (1210,6797) (1200,6878) (1190,7091) (1180,7500) (1170,7981) (1160,8346) (1150,8790) (1140,9470) (1130,9715) (1120,10293) (1110,10639) (1100,11136) (1090,11288) (1080,11713) (1070,12224) (1060,12652) (1050,13057) (1040,13733) (1030,14064) (1020,14333) (1010,15109) (1000,15082) (990,15118) (980,15440) (970,15566) (960,16294) (950,16368) (940,16640) (930,16899) (920,16539) (910,17351) (900,17089) (890,17138) (880,16936) (870,17233) (860,17155) (850,17439) (840,16933) (830,16801) (820,16903) (810,16639) (800,16061) (790,15862) (780,15540) (770,15881) (760,14992) (750,14778) (740,14413) (730,14061) (720,13761) (710,13365) (700,12795) (690,12094) (680,11942) (670,11579) (660,10532) (650,10727) (640,9990) (630,9674) (620,9512) (610,8621) (600,8412) (590,7958) (580,7304) (570,7139) (560,6412) (550,5974) (540,5654) (530,5086) (520,4796) (510,4216) (500,3769) (490,3275) (480,2812) (470,2439) (460,1785) (450,1737) (440,1107) (430,665) (420,431) (410,326) (400,204) (380,1) (370,3) (360,1) (350,3) (340,1) (330,1) (320,2) (310,2) (270,3) (260,3) (240,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505561. I believe that it has to do with the `ybar interval` option. If you remove `ybar interval` then it works.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked except that the bars were huge at first. But when I added `bar width = 1pt`, it looked exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- I am not an expert but I think I found an explanation.
- When I rotated the `x tick labels` by 90 degrees instead of 45 degrees, then it is more obvious what is probably happening: **The label is in the center of the interval.**
- Therefore I added another tick at 1800 so that the 1600 tick is shown.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{width=7.5cm,compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Score Distribution of the 1984 SAT},
    ybar interval,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    xlabel={SAT Scores},
    ylabel={Frequency},
    xmin=200, 
    xmax=1800, % Modified
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=18000,
    xtick={200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800}, % Modified
    ytick={0,3000,6000,9000,12000,15000,18000},
    x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east, align=left},
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xmajorgrids=false,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    enlarge x limits=0.03,
]

\addplot coordinates {(1600,5) (1580,27) (1570,19) (1560,39) (1550,75) (1540,96) (1530,108) (1520,188) (1510,217) (1500,278) (1490,316) (1480,404) (1470,473) (1460,617) (1450,601) (1440,795) (1430,874) (1420,1071) (1410,1196) (1400,1323) (1390,1439) (1380,1621) (1370,1871) (1360,2028) (1350,2267) (1340,2495) (1330,2698) (1320,3155) (1310,3334) (1300,3661) (1290,3730) (1280,4099) (1270,4393) (1260,4762) (1250,4923) (1240,5623) (1230,5701) (1220,6143) (1210,6797) (1200,6878) (1190,7091) (1180,7500) (1170,7981) (1160,8346) (1150,8790) (1140,9470) (1130,9715) (1120,10293) (1110,10639) (1100,11136) (1090,11288) (1080,11713) (1070,12224) (1060,12652) (1050,13057) (1040,13733) (1030,14064) (1020,14333) (1010,15109) (1000,15082) (990,15118) (980,15440) (970,15566) (960,16294) (950,16368) (940,16640) (930,16899) (920,16539) (910,17351) (900,17089) (890,17138) (880,16936) (870,17233) (860,17155) (850,17439) (840,16933) (830,16801) (820,16903) (810,16639) (800,16061) (790,15862) (780,15540) (770,15881) (760,14992) (750,14778) (740,14413) (730,14061) (720,13761) (710,13365) (700,12795) (690,12094) (680,11942) (670,11579) (660,10532) (650,10727) (640,9990) (630,9674) (620,9512) (610,8621) (600,8412) (590,7958) (580,7304) (570,7139) (560,6412) (550,5974) (540,5654) (530,5086) (520,4796) (510,4216) (500,3769) (490,3275) (480,2812) (470,2439) (460,1785) (450,1737) (440,1107) (430,665) (420,431) (410,326) (400,204) (380,1) (370,3) (360,1) (350,3) (340,1) (330,1) (320,2) (310,2) (270,3) (260,3) (240,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]